# Input Field Placeholder not working.?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>">
  <input type="search" class="search rm-input" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" placeholder "Your name here"/>
  <input type="submit" style="display:none" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x('Search', 'submit button'); ?>" />
</form>
```

I don't know why the placeholder text is not displaying in the field ...

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You missed out `'='` Should be:

```
placeholder="Your name here"
```

Comment: @SadiaRashid Mind providing screenshot of the input and inspect element on it?

Comment: added screenshot you can check

Comment: @SadiaRashid According to your provided screenshot, your placeholder is missing?

Comment: i dont know i have added that in the backend but when i inpect element it doesn't show up there ..

Comment: @SadiaRashid Then you have to check that yourself, from the code you given here, it seems you're missing "="

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114833/discussion-between-sadia-rashid-and-muthafury).

Comment: i have tried all answers given above .but its not working

Comment: I'm actually suspecting your css could be the cause.... Probably your input background is black, and on the same time your font color is also black, that's why you can't see, but from the screenshot, it doesn't seems like the css issue

Answer (score 2):

You forget `=` (equal) sign in your input fields.

```
<input type="search" class="search rm-input" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Your name here"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Missing `=` in `placeholder "Your name here"`

Placeholder text will be shown only if the value attribute is empty.In your example it has value, so value will be shown there.

With value

```
 <input type="search" class="search rm-input" value="My name" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Your name here"/>
```

Without value

```
   <input type="search" class="search rm-input" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Your name here"/>
```

> Refer : [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bjq09dnd/1/)

PS:
If you are using wordpress create searchform.php in your theme folder and add the form there .

Answer (score 2):

Placeholder doesn't work for Inputs that are not the types text so you will have to use value in your case like this `value="What you want to be displayed"`

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the placeholder color is not inherited from the parent, so it might be black, and invisible on black bg.

You can change it like this:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #ffffff;
}

input:-moz-placeholder { 
  color: #ffffff;
}

input::-ms-input-placeholder  { 
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

I used input as the selector, you should probably add some better specificity to that, maybe give that input and ID like "searchBar" then use the selector `input#searchBar`

Answer (score 1):

It's Resolved now it was a cache issue ...